# Is there a way to copy the contents of an ISO file to a specific windows partition and boot from it?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd.exe, diskpart, bcdedit

I'm currently trying to accomplish the following from the windows command line / powershell - create a bootable partition from an ISO, add a boot entry for it and boot from it.
It's important to note that the ISOs typically contain a small linux distro.
It must be all done via the command line, via another application (windows service, if it matters).

My progress so far:

1. Obtained the ISO file of DBAN ( or other wipe program, doesn't matter ) - Done.
2. Created partition - done with `diskpart`. I've created a `primary` partition with size of 10 GB. Formatted as FAT32. Assigned a letter to it, let's call it `X:`
3. Mounted the ISO file via `Mount-DiskImage` (Powershell) - mounts the image on a new volume, which I can later find via `wmic`. Let's name the volume of the ISO `Y:` for now.
4. Copied the files from the "iso partition" to `X:` with `xcopy  Y:\*.* X: /s/e/f`
5. Created a boot entry with bcdedit, using the following commands:

- `bcdedit /create /d "DBAN_Test" /application bootsector` - yields guid, i'll use {ID} for it.
- `bcdedit /set "{ID}" device partition=X:`
- `bcdedit /set "{ID}" path \ISOLINUX.BIN`, e.g. `X:\ISOLINUX.BIN`

Example output of `bcdedit` after (for the new entry):

```
Real-mode Boot Sector
---------------------
identifier           {ID}
device               partition=X:
path                 \ISOLINUX.BIN
description          DBAN_TEST
```

However, when I select it from the boot options, it gives me the following error:

```
isolinux: Failed to locate CD-ROM device; Boot failed.
```

I'd like to say that i've managed to achieve this using EasyBCD (GUI program), and it boots the DBAN successfully.
I'm assuming it's executing some of the commands I already did. It created an `AutoNeoGrub0.mbr` file in `C:\NST\`, and uses it as a `path` entry in the BCD entry.
However, EasyBCD is not usable in my case, I just wanted to check what entries it did create, nor do I have any idea how to create an MBR file like the `AutoNeoGrub0.mbr`.

Any advice or help on where i'm wrong will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need this to work on BIOS, UEFI or both? EasyBCD installs NeoGrub bootloader, which is a fork of GRUB4DOS - maybe you could use that one too.

Comment: I'd need it to work on both, but I would go for UEFI first. Thank you for the suggestion, I will try `GRUB4DOS` and drop the results :)

Comment: I've managed to do it successfully with `GRUB4DOS`. Will submit what i did as an asnwer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to do it using `GRUB4DOS`. This is what i did:

1. Downloaded `GRUB4DOS` and unzipped it in `C:\`
2. Created a boot entry with `bcdedit` which has `path  \grldr.mbr` and `device   partition=C:` (named it WipeISO)
3. Edited the `menu.lst` to contain:

```
color blue/green
timeout 5
default /default

title Boot Windows
fallback 2
find --set-root --ignore-floppies /bootmgr
chainloader /bootmgr
savedefault --wait=2

title Wipe ISO
find --set-root /iso/WipeISO.iso
map -heads=0 --sectors-per-track=0 /iso/WipeISO.iso (hd32)
map --hook
chainloader (hd32)
```

On reboot, i get 2 options - Windows and WipeISO. Selecting the second sucessfully runs the wipe program/distro.